# Get records with common values

Tags: sql, .net

Consider the following table

```
Employee Name | ZIP CODE 
--------------+----------
A             |  12345    
B             |  45678    
C             |  12345    
D             |  12345 
D             |  98765
```

I want to get distinct zip codes by passing Employee names i.e if I pass A only one record should return, but if I pass A, B no record should be returned as both rows not have common zip codes.

In case I pass A and D then only 1 ZIP code should be returned 12345.

How to get results using a SQL query?

Comment: you will pass the parameters to a procedure?? howcum passing diffrent no of paramaters!??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select zip_code
from t
where employee_name in ('A', 'B')
group by zip_code
having count(*) = 2;  -- number of employees in list
```

This assumes that the rows are unique.  If there could be duplicates, then change `count(*)` to `count(distinct employee_name)`.

Comment: Still not getting required result set.If A and D is passed result should contain only one zip code.

Comment: Check again. On this [demo](https://rextester.com/EFY23119) seem to work as expected.

Comment: Yes i have checked. It works on demo , but there is one problem. If i pass only A , it should return 12345.

Comment: If you pass only `A` you need to change  `= 2` to `= 1` he told you use the number of employees in list

Comment: The number of Parameters passed are defined by search criteria. No fix number , it can be changed.

Comment: Then you need pass that number as a parameter aswells

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any way to calculate count number from query dynamically rather passing as parameter.